# Datagrid in delete the row

Tags: c#

I am using delete row index to delete a row in datagridview.

But when one row is deleted then datagridview automatically appends next row

first time any index is deleted then itscorrect but at the second time row-1 indexed row is deleted

I am using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
{
    lpath.Add(path[i].ToString());
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(int.Parse(arr[i]));
}
```

Comment: You can not explain the problem well...you should try to learning english much more

Comment: What is a error are you getting?

Comment: @نرخیاب Interesting...the one lecturing on English needs an English lecture too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see it you skew the index off the `dataGridView1` the first time.

lets say you have a list with element `{1,2,3,4,5}` if we now remove index 3 and then 4 we the end up removing 3 and 5 giving us the list `{1,2,4}` but we wanted to remove 3 and 4 not 3 and 5

what i think you want to do is to get all indexes you want to remove, and the order them and remove from top to bottom so instead of removing 3 an 4 in that order you remove 4 and 3 giving us the list `{1,2,5}`

```
List<int> RemoveList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
{
    lpath.Add(path[i].ToString());
    RemoveList.Add(int.Parse(arr[i]));
}

//Remove highest index first.
RemoveList.OrderByDescending(a=>a);
for (int i = 0; i < RemoveList.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(RemoveList[i]);
}
```

Comment: for (int i = path.length-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(int.Parse(arr[i]));
} //like this

Answer (score 1):

you have to reduce the 'i' after you delete a row when using for loop

See the following code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
{
   lpath.Add(path[i].ToString());
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(int.Parse(arr[i]));
  i--;  }
```

Comment: no its not infintly in path varibale i have selected record available

Comment: path and arr have same number of element

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit weird to increase **i** within the **for loop** than decrease it. Why don't you add the items than clear all rows ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++) {
    lpath.Add(path[i].ToString());
}
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```